# Access email inbox using php

Tags: php

I want to display email inbox of any free email service like yahoo or rediff using php. How can i do this ?

Comment: before asking, search for already exists solutions

Comment: @eskimo : i tried gmail using imap in php but its not worked.

Comment: @Rijin: i tried some codes but not find any solution

Comment: So post the code that didn't work so people can help you with that. Nobody is going to write the code for you

Comment: check this for accessing gmail : https://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: @eskimo : here is code 

<?php
$imap = imap_open("{pop.example.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "username", "password");

if( $imap ) {
   
     //Check no.of.msgs
     $num = imap_num_msg($imap);

     //if there is a message in your inbox
     if( $num >0 ) {
          //read that mail recently arrived
          echo imap_qprint(imap_body($imap, $num));
     }

     //close the stream
     imap_close($imap);
}
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest Example i can give for you as a beginner is.

Sign Up for a GMAIL (google email) account.

get the SMTP and POP3 info for their SMTP/Mail Servers.

Read up on SMTP and POP3, as it is a simple protocol.

SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

POP3 (Post office Protocol 3) - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc728365(v=ws.10).aspx

you'll be making a server-sided email client.
so set up your server to not timeout for atleast 2/5minutes (script max execution time) use php.ini or ini_set() command...

connect to the server via TCP, and start with the Authentication process
as stated according to the SMTP PROTOCOL.
form here on out all you have to do is work on it and you will be able to do it

Comment: read up on data connections and transferring between servers with PHP

Comment: Further that with the study of playing with Telnet to understand the SMTP from a server point of view and not a Source code/Language dependent view.